# Syntax Error near SQLSTATE

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-8.2

I got a plpgsql function here to indicate if any warning raised during `ANALYZE`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION analyzeWarning() RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
  warningRaised int;
BEGIN
  warningRaised := 0;
  FOR i IN 1..10
  LOOP
    BEGIN
      ANALYZE;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN SQLSTATE '01000' THEN return 1;
    END;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN 0;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This function kept giving me syntax error near:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SQLSTATE"
LINE 11:           WHEN SQLSTATE '01000' THEN return 1;
```

I am not sure where I missed the syntax error.

My postgres build is 8.2.15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL 8.2.15 is pretty old unsupported release. This release doesn't support `SQLSTATE` constant there.

But your code should not to work on any PostgreSQL release. You cannot to trap warnings or notices in PostgreSQL. Only exceptions are trappable.